# Is it possible to show swipe refresh indicator with animation using setRefreshing() method

Tags: android, parallax, swiperefreshlayout

I have to implement both `Parallax` animation and `Swipe to refresh` for my `ListView`. While dragging the list view to down , the listview header image should show parallax animation. And when the parallax animation exceeds a limit list view should show swipe to refresh indicator. I know it is possible by using `setRefreshing(true)` . But by using this method won't show animation for refresh indicator like it is sliding from top.

So is there any way to show refresh indicator with default animation at runtime?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutListing"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <com.xxx.views.ParallaxListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fadingEdge="none"
            android:overScrollMode="never" >
        </com.xxx.views.ParallaxListView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

public class ParallaxListView extends ListView implements OnScrollListener {

    public final static double ZOOM_X2 = 2;
    private Context context = null;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private int mDrawableMaxHeight = -1;
    private int mImageViewHeight = -1;
    private int mDefaultImageViewHeight = 0;
    private double mZoomRatio;

    private int firstVisibleItem  =0;

    private int lastTopValueAssigned;

    private Handler uiHandler =  new Handler();

    private boolean isRefreshListView = false;

    private interface OnOverScrollByListener {
        public boolean overScrollBy(int deltaX, int deltaY, int scrollX,
                                    int scrollY, int scrollRangeX, int scrollRangeY,
                                    int maxOverScrollX, int maxOverScrollY, boolean isTouchEvent);
    }

    private interface OnTouchEventListener {
        public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Constructor for ParallaxListView.
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     * @param defStyle
     */
    public ParallaxListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);

    }

    /**
     * 
     * Constructor for ParallaxListView.
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     */
    public ParallaxListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public ParallaxListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public void init(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        //setOnScrollListener(this);
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                mDefaultImageViewHeight =  context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dflt,context.getTheme()).getIntrinsicHeight();
            } else {
                mDefaultImageViewHeight = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dflt).getIntrinsicHeight();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

  /*
   * (non-Javadoc)
   * @see android.widget.AbsListView#onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int)
   */
    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                initViewsBounds(mZoomRatio);
            }
        });

    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener#onScrollStateChanged(android.widget.AbsListView, int)
     */
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.view.View#overScrollBy(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, boolean)
     */
    @Override
    protected boolean overScrollBy(int deltaX, int deltaY, int scrollX,
                                   int scrollY, int scrollRangeX, int scrollRangeY,
                                   int maxOverScrollX, int maxOverScrollY, boolean isTouchEvent) {
        boolean isCollapseAnimation = false;
        isCollapseAnimation = scrollByListener.overScrollBy(deltaX, deltaY,
                scrollX, scrollY, scrollRangeX, scrollRangeY, maxOverScrollX,
                maxOverScrollY, isTouchEvent)
                || isCollapseAnimation;
        return isCollapseAnimation ? true : super.overScrollBy(deltaX, deltaY,
                scrollX, scrollY, scrollRangeX, scrollRangeY, maxOverScrollX,
                maxOverScrollY, isTouchEvent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                         int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        this.firstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
        parallaxImage(mImageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        if(mImageView != null){ 
            View firstView = (View) mImageView.getParent();
            // firstView.getTop < getPaddingTop means mImageView will be covered by top padding,
            // so we can layout it to make it shorter
            if (firstView.getTop() < getPaddingTop() && mImageView.getHeight() > mImageViewHeight) {
                mImageView.getLayoutParams().height = Math.max(mImageView.getHeight() - (getPaddingTop() - firstView.getTop()), mImageViewHeight);
                // to set the firstView.mTop to 0,
                // maybe use View.setTop() is more easy, but it just support from Android 3.0 (API 11)
                firstView.layout(firstView.getLeft(), 0, firstView.getRight(), firstView.getHeight());
                mImageView.requestLayout();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        touchListener.onTouchEvent(ev);
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    public void setParallaxImageView(ImageView iv) {
        try {
            mImageView = iv;
            mImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    private void initViewsBounds(double zoomRatio) {
        if (mImageViewHeight == -1) {
            mImageViewHeight = mImageView.getMeasuredHeight();
            if (mImageViewHeight <= 0) {
                mImageViewHeight = mDefaultImageViewHeight;
            }
            double ratio = ((double) mImageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth()) / ((double) mImageView.getWidth());

            mDrawableMaxHeight = (int) ((mImageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight() / ratio) * (zoomRatio > 1 ?
                    zoomRatio : 1));
        }
    }

    public void setZoomRatio(double zoomRatio) {
        mZoomRatio = zoomRatio;
    }


    private OnOverScrollByListener scrollByListener = new OnOverScrollByListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean overScrollBy(int deltaX, int deltaY, int scrollX,
                                    int scrollY, int scrollRangeX, int scrollRangeY,
                                    int maxOverScrollX, int maxOverScrollY, boolean isTouchEvent) {

            if (mImageView.getHeight() <= mDrawableMaxHeight && isTouchEvent) {
                if (deltaY < 0) {
                    if (mImageView.getHeight() - deltaY / 2 >= mImageViewHeight) {
                        if(mImageView.getHeight() > (mDrawableMaxHeight * 0.70)){
                            //here i want to show refresh indicator 
                        }
                        mImageView.getLayoutParams().height = mImageView.getHeight() - deltaY / 2 < mDrawableMaxHeight ?
                                mImageView.getHeight() - deltaY / 2 : mDrawableMaxHeight;
                        mImageView.requestLayout();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (mImageView.getHeight() > mImageViewHeight) {
                        mImageView.getLayoutParams().height = mImageView.getHeight() - deltaY > mImageViewHeight ?
                                mImageView.getHeight() - deltaY : mImageViewHeight;
                        mImageView.requestLayout();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };


    private void fireSwipeToRefresh(){
        if(!isRefreshListView){
            uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        isRefreshListView = true;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(INTENT_ACTION_SWIPE_TO_REFRESH);
                        intent.putExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_FIRST_VISIBLE_INDEX, firstVisibleItem);
                        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
                    }
                }) ;
        }
    }

    private OnTouchEventListener touchListener = new OnTouchEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                isRefreshListView = false;
                if (mImageViewHeight - 1 < mImageView.getHeight()) {
                    ResetAnimimation animation = new ResetAnimimation(
                            mImageView, mImageViewHeight);
                    animation.setDuration(400);
                    animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
                    mImageView.startAnimation(animation);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public class ResetAnimimation extends Animation {
        private int targetHeight;
        private int originalHeight;
        private int extraHeight;
        private View mView;

        protected ResetAnimimation(View view, int targetHeight) {
            this.mView = view;
            this.targetHeight = targetHeight;
            originalHeight = view.getHeight();
            extraHeight = this.targetHeight - originalHeight;
        }

        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime,
                Transformation t) {
            int newHeight;
            newHeight = (int) (targetHeight - extraHeight * (1 - interpolatedTime));
            mView.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
            mView.requestLayout();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put your listView inside your swipe to refresh layout like this.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/images_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/imagesList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="05dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0.0sp" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this will help you...

Comment: Yes. This is what I did. I want to show refresh indicator with default animation(sliding from top to down)  while dragging listview down along with  parallax animation